# Merge menus for mobile menu

Tags: 8, navigation

Hi I have 3 menus on my site and for display on mobile/tablet I would like to merge these menus to only 1 menu. Do you know how to do it. I tried to use [menu_tree_all_data](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21core%21includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/8)

and then merge them but I get Call to undefined function menu_tree_all_data. I'am confused that the function doesn't exist.

Comment: [`menu_tree_all_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7.x) doesn't exist in D8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm also looking for a solution to this issue I've come a bit further and maybe it will get you in the right direction.

To load a menu in Drupal 8 you can put this in a `theme_preprocess_page` in your `.theme`-file.

```
  $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
  $menu_name = 'main';

  // Build the typical default set of menu tree parameters.
  $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);

  // Load the tree based on this set of parameters.
  $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);

  // Transform the tree using the manipulators you want.
  $manipulators = array(
    // Only show links that are accessible for the current user.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
    // Use the default sorting of menu links.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
  );
  $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);

  // Finally, build a renderable array from the transformed tree.
  $menu = $menu_tree->build($tree);
  $menu_html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($menu);
```

I have not yet worked out how to merge different menus into one big menu but I will let you know if I come up with a solution.
You can find out more about the code above at [Drupal 8.2.x » menu.api.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!menu.api.php/group/menu/8.2.x#sec_rendering) which is where I found it.

Ok, I now have found the solution which I found in the module [Responsive and off-canvas menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menu)

```
  $menus = array("main-menu","footer-menu","utility-menu");

  $combined_tree = array();
  $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
  $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters(trim($menus[0]));
  $manipulators = array(
    // Show links to nodes that are accessible for the current user.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkNodeAccess'),
    // Only show links that are accessible for the current user.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
    // Use the default sorting of menu links.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
  );
  // Force the entire tree to be build by setting expandParents to an
  // empty array.
  $parameters->expandedParents = array();
  // Iterate over the menus and merge them together.
  foreach($menus as $menu_name) {
    $tree_items = $menu_tree->load(trim($menu_name), $parameters);
    $tree_manipulated = $menu_tree->transform($tree_items, $manipulators);
    $combined_tree = array_merge($combined_tree, $tree_manipulated);
  }

  $menu = $menu_tree->build($combined_tree);

  $vars['mobile_menu'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="off-canvas-wrapper"><div id="off-canvas">',
    '#suffix' => '</div></div>',
    '#markup' => \Drupal::service("renderer")->renderRoot($menu),
  );
```

If you put this in your `theme_preprocess_page` in your `.theme`-file you could then in your `page.html.twig` print the twig variable `{{ mobile_menu }}`.

Comment: Make sure `$vars` corresponds to the function parameter:

`MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars){

}`

Comment: Also `'#prefix'` and `'#suffix'` seem to break things for me... Not had time to look into this... :)